# What are the differences between ClockworkMod and Team Win Recovery for the Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, twrp

My Nexus 7 is running on 4.2.1 and has the latest build version. According to the Nexus 7 Root Toolkit, it is giving me an option to flash one of the following recovery menus:

1. CWM Touch
2. TWRP Touch

What is the difference between them? How can I determine which would be most suitable for me?

Comment: I voted to close this, as the "Which is better..." part cannot be answered on facts, it will be the opinion of the person answering.

Comment: I think the "What is the difference between them" makes this question fine, just delete the 'suitable' bit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm partial to TWRP.  The biggest difference I've noticed is that CWM requires you to either boot into recovery or use Rom Manager to flash a rom, while TWRP allows any program with root access (goo manager, Rom Toolbox, etc) to flash roms.  There are probably some other differences, but this was the big one for me.

Comment: That is the point of CWM, boot into a alternate rooted Android environment to perform the backup/restore in a "safe" manner... :)

Comment: Are the backups generated by CWM and TWRP interchangeable?

Comment: Yeah, TWRP can do that too, but you can also queue up actions from within the GooManager, at which point it will reboot and flash it for you.  CWM requires you to use Rom Manager to do this.

Answer (score 3):

**TeamWin Recovery Project** (TWRP) - This is a very widely used custom recovery. It is fully touch-driven, has one of the most complete feature sets available, and uses a themable UI. TWRP is maintained by Ethan Yonker (Dees Troy) and sees a number of contributions from the community via OmniROM's code review.

**ClockworkMod Recovery** (CWM or CWMR) - This is one of the original custom recoveries that is still widely used today. Most of its functionality was written by Koushik Dutta (Koush), but it has since seen significant code contributions come from the community via CyanogenMod's code review. Several variants are available, including: standard (hardware keys navigate the menus), swipe (basic up/down/left/right navigation by swiping), and touch (fully touch-driven menus). More information on ClockworkMod usage can be found at ClockWorkMod Recovery Instructions.

**Active Development:** **T**eam**W**in **R**ecovery **P**roject(TWRP) and CMR(**C**yanogen**M**od **R**ecovery)
**Development Ceased:** **C**lock**W**ork**M**od **R**ecovery(CWM or CWMR) and PhilZ Touch

[source](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/All_About_Recovery_Images)